# Pegar apenas ultimo registro consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT  
     CODIGO,
     DTINICIO AS INICIO,
     DTFINAL  AS  FINAL
    FROM PFHSTAFT
    WHERE
     EMPRESA =1 
        GROUP BY
          CODIGO,
          DTFINAL,
          DTINICIO
```

Ela retorna da seguinte forma:

```
0031    2000-11-06 00:00:00.000 2001-12-31 00:00:00.000
0031    2002-02-26 00:00:00.000 2002-06-30 00:00:00.000
0031    2002-09-26 00:00:00.000 2008-03-17 00:00:00.000  <<<<<
0051    2003-04-23 00:00:00.000 2016-09-05 00:00:00.000
0051    2016-10-06 00:00:00.000 2016-10-15 00:00:00.000
0051    2016-10-18 00:00:00.000 2016-10-22 00:00:00.000  <<<<<
0051    2016-11-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Mas preciso que seja listado somente a última data final de cada funcionário, que é representado pelo código:

```
 0031   2002-09-26 00:00:00.000 2008-03-17 00:00:00.000
 0051   2016-10-18 00:00:00.000 2016-10-22 00:00:00.000
```

Já tentei usar o max mas não me atendeu; alguém sabe o que pode ser?

BANCO: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Linhas em que a colunas de data estejam sem informação (NULL) devem ser ignoradas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem várias alternativas, vou deixar aqui uma que faz uso da "função de janela" [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql).

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  EMPRESA,
            CODIGO,
            DTINICIO AS INICIO,
            DTFINAL  AS  FINAL,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPRESA, CODIGO ORDER BY DTFINAL DESC) RN
      FROM PFHSTAFT  
)
SELECT CODIGO, 
       INICIO,
       FINAL
  FROM cte
 WHERE RN = 1
   AND EMPRESA = 1
```

Comment: A utilização da função row_number() realmente é a abordagem tradicional, para versão 2008. A definição do particionamento em OVER() ficou perfeita, colocando também a coluna EMPRESA, mesmo que no exemplo conste somente uma empresa. // A princípio seria recomendado colocar os filtros de leitura de dados* na CTE, pois assim pode retornar menor número de linhas na CTE. Entretanto, o otimizador de consultas é esperto o suficiente para fazer isso por conta própria. // (*) No caso, seria mover o filtro EMPRESA = 1 para dentro da CTE

Answer (score 0):

Pode testar:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA A WHERE A.DATA = (SELECT MAX(A1.DATA) FROM TABELA A1 WHERE A1. CHAVE = A.CHAVE... AND A1.DATA <= SYSDATE);
```

Obs.: Se for Oracle é `SYSDATE`.

```
SELECT A.CODIGO, A.DTINICIO AS INICIO, A.DTFINAL AS FINAL FROM PFHSTAFT A WHERE A.DTFINAL = (SELECT MAX(A1.DTFINAL) FROM PFHSTAFT A1 WHERE A1.DTFINAL <= SYSDATE) AND EMPRESA =1 GROUP BY A.CODIGO, A.DTFINAL, A.DTINICIO;
```

Considerando que `DTFINAL` seja uma chave da sua tabela, você diz que quer para o campo `DTFINAL` a maior data (para as mesmas chaves) . Por isso usar o `MAX` e fazer um join com a tabela do subselect. O `SYSDATE` você diz que a maior data tem que ser menor ou igual à data atual.

Comment: Não entendi. Poderia explicar? Se for possível usando a tabela da pergunta seria melhor. Se formatar seu código, vai ficar mais fácil de ler

Comment: Editei para detalhar melhor. Mas se ficar dúvidas, pergunte.