# Retornar ultimo registro de cada objeto

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
         imovel
ano | id |  item | valor
```

Registros:

```
2000| 1 |  201 | null
2001| 1 |  211 | 10
2002| 1 |  202 | null
2000| 2 |  201 | null
2001| 2 |  221 | 17
2002| 2 |  211 | 14
2000| 3 |  201 | null
```

O que preciso e que sempre retorne de cada id apenas o ultimo registro filtrado pelo ultimo ano e do item que for filtrar, sendo que os 2 primeiros caracteres do item faz referencia ao mesmo e o ultimo caractere faz referencia a opção do item (ex: A consulta do item 201 deve retornar 2 registros referentes aos id 2 e 3. O id 1 não deve ser retornado porque sua ultima atualização do  item foi feita em 2002 onde o item 20 está com a opção 2).

Comment: quais as linhas retornariam na sua amostragem ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar apenas ultimo registro consulta sql server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218904/pegar-apenas-ultimo-registro-consulta-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu precebi o que precisava era de pegar o valor de cada id onde o ano fosse maior, se for isso tente o seguinte código.

tente este código:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel 
WHERE id=1 AND item=201 
ORDER BY year DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Linhas retornadas:

```
         imovel
ano | id | item | valor

2000| 1 |  201 | null
```

**EDIT1 - RESPOSTA MAIS CERTA**

Reli novamente a sua questão e penso ter percebido melhor a dúvida teste o seguinte código:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel
WHERE id=1 AND mid(item, 1, 2)=20
ORDER BY mid(item, 3, 1) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Faço um `select` todos os registo com `id=1` onde os **2** primeiros caracteres do campo item correspondam aos primeiros **2** da consulta "**20**1" depois vou ordenar a lista de forma decrescente através do último (00**0**) carácter do campo item, para concluir limito a consulta a só uma linha de registo.

Vai lhe dar então a seguinte resposta:

```
         imovel
ano | id | item | valor
2002| 1  | 202  | null
```

O resultado não lhe interessa, então ignora, para os restantes `id` basta mudar no `where` onde tem `id=1` passaria a `id=2`; `id=3`....

Espero ter ajudado mais desta vez.

**EDIT2 - LOOP**

Deixo aqui dois sites com exemplos de como fazer um `loop`, o qual vai servir para ir somando os id:

- [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html)
- [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql)

Será também necessário para não aparecerem os valores "202" pode ser feita uma condição `if`:

- [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: Então. Mais não pode vir registro caso o imóvel esteja com item 202 com ano posterior.

Comment: podes me dizer das 7 linhas que tens com registos quais os que te interessam, exemplo: linha 3, 6 e 7 onde o ano é o maior de cada id. Só intenderei o que precisas, para te ajudar melhor

Comment: Entendeu errado. Os 2 primeiros carácteres do item é o que identifica o item. O último carácter e a opção que ele seleciona no sistema. Então dentro do item 20 pode ter 1,2,3,4,5 e ficaria 201, 202, 203, etc. E só pode retornar a linha que tiver por exemplo 201 de todos IDs como última edição. Se tiver 201 no último ano de insert deste id retorna a linha. Mais se tiver 201 no ano de 2002 e 202 em 2003 não pode retornar.

Comment: Vi a sua reedição. Mais isso deve fazer para todos IDs para eu ter o retorno de todos ao mesmo tempo. Sei que tá bem estranho está tabela. Mais é de 1998 este sistema.

Comment: A linha 4 e 7 devem ser retornadas. A primeira linha mesmo tendo 201 e sendo outro ID não pode ser retornada porque a linha 3 tem 202. A linha 3 índica que é de um ano posterior é o principal que 20 e o item e 2 e a opção deste item.

Comment: Estou a perceber a sua necessidade, e penso que o meu código já o consegue ajudar a fazer o que quer, bastava arranjar forma de mostrar todos ao mesmo tempo. Vou tentar dar uma olhada a ver se consigo arranjar melhor o query. Com vai ser feito o select? ->direto na base de dados ou ->vai ter algum software/pagina a fazer a consulta, se for a segunda opção sempre pode fazer algo tipo um FOR "for i = 1 to 3 do (select * fr.... id=i ....limit 1) if item = 201 then writetxt"

Comment: Vai ser direto no banco. Tenho varias tabelas a fazer isto, mais todas com o mesmo layout. Preciso fazer um relatório já que o software não tem este relatório. E uma tabela bem confusa, quando vi hoje pela manha ate demorei de entender como funcionava.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas pode fazer inserção com um contador

```
select count(id) from imovel where ano = 2000
```

Dai você sé precisa salvar o resultado em uma variável incrementar +1 que sempre terá uma sequência.

Comment: Não não. O filtro será da ultima alteração do item por ano